# pulseaudio: Play audio on multiple computers simultaneously over network

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio

I have two computers on the same network, both of which have speakers attached and are running `pulseaudio`.  How can I play sound on one of them and have it come out of both speakers?  I'd prefer to set this up via the CLI / config files, instead of GUI tools.

Comment: Helpful link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Enable network output

On both machines, install `pulseaudio-zeroconf`.

On the source machine, edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to contain

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-zeroconf-discover
```

On the destination machine, edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to contain

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

Copy `$HOME/.config/pulse/cookie` from one machine to the other, so they both have the same contents.

Restart pulseaudio on both machines

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

On the source machine, run

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

You should see several sinks whose name starts with `tunnel.{destination_machine_hostname}.{remote_sink_name}`. Playing audio to them should play on the other computer.

### Enable combined output

From the sink list you just made, pick out which local sink and which remote sink you want to play audio to. Note the `name` (inside the angle brackets).

From the source machine, run

```
pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves={local_sink_name},tunnel.{destination_machine_hostname}.{remote_sink_name}
```

(You can edit this into the `default.pa` without the `pactl` to create the combined sink automatically)

Playing sound to this combined sink should now play out of the selected devices on both machines.

Comment: I'm not seeing output on list-sinks. I guess it's likely a firewall or discovery issue. Is there a way to specify a specific ip? Which server (the source or destination) needs a port open?

Comment: zeroconf will only work if both machines are on the same subnet. If zeroconf is not working for you, it looks like you can use [module-tunnel-{sink,source}](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-tunnel-sinksource) to set up the tunnel manually. Alternatively, [maybe you just need to restart Avahi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472368/56043)? See [the documentation on remote streaming](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/) for more options / details.

Comment: Also, make sure you copied the cookie over to be the same on both machines or nothing will work.

Comment: rebooting helped, but the whole thing was so finiky that I just gave up and use aux cables now.